# paperclip image is not saving

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip

I am using paperclip gem to upload the images but the image is not saving.

Here is my Photo model:

```
class Photo < ApplicationRecord
belongs_to :room


has_attached_file :image, styles: {medium: '300x300>', thumb: '100x100>'},
                  :path => ':rails_root/public/images/:id/:style/:filename',
                  :url => '/images/:id/:style/:filename'
validates_attachment_content_type :image, content_type: /\Aimage\/.*\z/
    # do_not_validate_attachment_file_type :image
end
```

Room model:

```
class Room < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :user
    has_many :photos
end
```

form:

```
<%= file_field_tag "images[]", type: :file, multiple: true %>
```

controller:

```
def create
    @room = current_user.rooms.build(room_params)

    if @room.save

        if params[:images]
            params[:images].each do |image|
                @room.photos.create(image: image)
            end
        end

        @photos = @room.photos
        redirect_to edit_room_path(@room), notice: 'Saved...'
    else
        render :new
    end
end
```

Only room is saving but not the photo model. I tried to save images using relationship but not working even without relationship image is not saving. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved. I had to upgrade ImageMagick. Thank you all

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to suggest to a solution like this.
Change **create** to **create!** to raise an exception and then you can debug better.

```
def create
    @room = current_user.rooms.build(room_params)

    if @room.save

        if params[:images]
            params[:images].each do |image|
                @room.photos.create!(image: image)
            end
        end

        @photos = @room.photos
        redirect_to edit_room_path(@room), notice: 'Saved...'
    else
        render :new
    end
end
```

You can also try removing styles key to see if something is wrong with generating other images, maybe ImageMagick is not installed.

Answer (score 0):

Hard to say where exactly problem lies. Looks like u using paperclip
has_attached_file method. Probably your uploaded image does not meet validation and its type isnt like something "image/jpg", "image/jpeg", "image/png", "image/gif" etc types. Can u provide what image u trying to save.

Comment: try not using path maybe. https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip/wiki/Changing-attachment-:path
or debug somewhere in task